# Breakline not working SSRS formula or calculated fields?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

[picture probleme breakline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls2CZ.png)
, I have a problem with my breakline not working properly in my either caculated fields or my expression.
I would like to split by created date and title etc...
do you know why it is not working ?

```
    =  "<b>"+ "Created on: " + "</b>" & CDate(Fields!ticket_ticketSolutions_date_create.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm") 
 
& Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine &

"<b>" + "Approval date: " + "</b>" &  iif(IsNothing(Fields!date_approval.value),"Not Approved",CDate( Fields!date_approval.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm"))

& Environment.NewLine &

Environment.NewLine &

 "<b>" + "Solutions: " +"</b>" & Fields!ticket_ticketSolutions_content_plainText.Value
```

```
=Join( LookupSet(Fields!ticket_tickets_sourceId.value, Fields!itemId.value, Fields!start_end_solution_data.value, "Ticket_ticket_ticket_Solutions"), vbcrlf)
```

[calculated fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L6bI.png) ,
[expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT19a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using HTML tags in your text box. When using HTML, line breaks do not work.

Replace the NewLine with the HTML break tag `<br>`.

```
=  "<b>"+ "Created on: " + "</b>" & CDate(Fields!ticket_ticketSolutions_date_create.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm") & 
"<br><br>" & "<b>" + "Approval date: " + "</b>" &  
IIF(IsNothing(Fields!date_approval.value), "Not Approved", CDate( Fields!date_approval.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm")) & 
"<br>" & "<br>" & "<b>" + "Solutions: " +"</b>" & Fields!ticket_ticketSolutions_content_plainText.Value
```

Comment: what about extra space between title and text ?

Comment: @Jack_paul - Extra space? Title?